# Getting strings from an Sql Q, placing them in a List<> that will be for a ComboBox

Tags: c#

I got problems with the Sql to List to Items for the ComboBox. I tried the next code but i always get blank comboBox, but when i use the QuickWatch the list got some numbers instead of strings.

```
List<List<String>> ResultSet = new List<List<String>>();
 string qString = "";
        if (Form2.Price == "1" && Form4.Length == "1")
            qString = "SELECT CameraAngle FROM Games WHERE(Cost > 0) AND(Length > 20) AND(Category = '" + Form3.Requirements + "') AND(Requirements = '" + Form5.Category + "') GROUP BY CameraAngle";
        if (Form2.Price== "1" && Form4.Length == "0")
            qString = "SELECT CameraAngle FROM Games WHERE(Cost > 0) AND(Length < 20) AND(Category = N'" + Form3.Requirements + "') AND(Requirements = N'" + Form5.Category + "') GROUP BY CameraAngle";
        if (Form2.Price== "0" && Form4.Length == "1")
            qString = "SELECT CameraAngle FROM Games WHERE(Cost = 0) AND(Length > 20) AND(Category = N'" + Form3.Requirements + "') AND(Requirements = N'" + Form5.Category + "') GROUP BY CameraAngle";
        if (Form2.Price== "0" && Form4.Length == "0")
            qString = "SELECT CameraAngle FROM Games WHERE(Cost = 0) AND(Length < 20) AND(Category = N'" + Form3.Requirements + "') AND(Requirements = N'" + Form5.Category + "') GROUP BY CameraAngle";

        using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = 'C:...\Database1.mdf'; Integrated Security = True"))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qString, connection);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var rec = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= reader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    rec.Add(reader.GetString(i));
                }
                ResultSet.Add(rec);
            }
        }

        foreach (List<string> x in ResultSet)
        {
            cbView.Items.Add(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, x.ToString()));
        }
```

The thing is that this code worked when the sql was like "Select Category from Games" but now when i got external parameters it doesnt work. Help please :D

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see what query you're building and whether that query actually returns data from the db?

Comment: @LarryBud I tried with the sql wizzard and it gives me what i need, but when i try to call it like the wizzard sql it gives me the error something like "the new returning schema is different than the base one".

Comment: No, I mean stepped through using Visual Studio.  What's the value of qString that it's executing?

Comment: @LarryBud oh the value of qString is good, it returns "select CameraView from Games where (Cost > 0) and (Length >20) and (Category = Strategy) and (Requirements = High) group by CameraAngle" example.

Comment: I think you need to learn how to debug in Visual Studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

There's no way for us to know what "doesn't work" just by you telling us that it doesn't work.